# Concatenating the contents of multiple files passed from command line

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, concatenation, file-handling

I am trying to concatenate the contents of all the `argv[]` arguments passed while executing the code. count here is the same as `argc`. **files contains `argv`.

```
char *merge_everything(int count, char **files) {
        size_t size = 0;
        char *buf = NULL;
        buf = malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(*buf)); /* size + 1 byte for the \0 */
        if (buf == NULL) {
            printf("MALLOC ERROR\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        char *temp = buf;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
            FILE *f = fopen(files[i], "rb");
    
            fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
            long bytes = ftell(f);
            fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    
            fread(temp, (size_t) bytes, 1, f);
            temp += bytes;
            fclose(f);
        }
        *temp = 0;
        free(buf); //If I don't free buf here then memory leak? If I do temp has null?
        return temp; //temp has all the concatenated stuff
    }
```

I am in this dilemma that freeing `buf` at the end is preceding the `return` statement.
Please help me rectify the approach.
I am keen on using buffer (via `malloc`) instead of writing it into a new file. Hence, this approach.

Comment: *If I don't free buf here then memory leak*. Firstly you should be returning `buf` not `temp` as the former is the start of the string whereas the latter is somewhere in the middle of the string. Secondly, if that is done then it is not a memory leak as the caller is then responsible for doing the free.

Comment: Do you realize that the amount of memory you allocate isn't at all related to the size of any one file, much less all of them?

Comment: `size_t size = 0; malloc((size + 1) * sizeof(*buf)); ` How much memory do you think that allocates?

Comment: That allocates nothing. I realized that but instead of giving it a hardcoded macro like 512 or something. I want it to be adaptive to the file 1 size then file 2 size and so on.

Comment: Fair enough. But it doesn't happen magically. Where is the code to do that? Once the allocation is made it doesn't change size automatically.

Comment: temp has been keeping track of where 1 file ends and where to start reading the next file in the buffer. So, it moves farther from the origin over time. We return buf because it is still at the 0 mark?

Comment: Well if you don't return the start of the buffer how do you expect the caller to know where the data starts?

Comment: btw, If I return buf here at the end of the function, how do I free the memory malloc is supposed to provide?

Comment: you must not free the memory. If should be freed by the caller when it is not needed anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You allocate 1 byte and read plenty. It is Undefined Behaviour.
2. You need to increase the allocated memory size for every file.
3. You should check file I/O errors.
4. I do not know why `count-1` but maybe you have your reasons.

```
char *merge_everything(int count, char **files) {
        size_t size = 0;
        long bytes;
        char *buf = NULL, *temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++) {
            FILE *f = fopen(files[i], "rb");
    
            fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
            bytes = ftell(f);
            fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);

            
            temp = realloc(buf, size + bytes);
            if(!temp)
            {
                free(buf);
                break;
            }
            buf = temp;
    
            fread(buf + size, (size_t) bytes, 1, f);
            size += bytes;
            fclose(f);
        }
        return buf; //temp has all the concatenated stuff
    }
```

Comment: This helps! About your statement "the caller should free memory", I am guessing that could be done by freeing the char * which collects buf, right?

Comment: Also, in your fread(), how can I get rid of the \n characters? it is tricky because we are keeping track of bytes read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grow the buffer as you go.  eg:

```
/* Read all named files into a buffer. */                                          
                                                                                   
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
#include <stddef.h>                                                                
#include <ctype.h>                                                                 
#include <stdlib.h>                                                                
                                                                                   
struct buffer {                                                                    
        char *start;                                                               
        char *end;                                                                 
        size_t cap;                                                                
};                                                                                 
                                                                                   
void push(int c, struct buffer *);                                                 
int pop(struct buffer *a);                                                         
void * xrealloc(void *buf, size_t num, size_t siz, void *endvp);                   
FILE * xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode);                                 
                                                                                   
int                                                                                
main(int argc, char **argv)                                                        
{                                                                                  
        struct buffer a = {0};                                                     
        int c;                                                                     
        for( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ ){                                           
                FILE *ifp = xfopen(argv[i], "r");                                  
                while( (c = fgetc(ifp)) != EOF ) {                                 
                        push(c, &a);                                               
                }                                                                  
        }                                                                          
        while( (c = pop(&a)) != EOF ) {                                            
                putchar(c);                                                        
        }                                                                          
        return 0;                                                                  
} 

                                                                                   
int                                                                                
pop(struct buffer *a)                                                              
{                                                                                  
        return (a->start < a->end) ? *a->start++ : EOF;                            
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
void                                                                               
push(int c, struct buffer *b)                                                      
{                                                                                  
        if( b->start == NULL || b->end >= b->start + b->cap ) {                    
                b->start = xrealloc(b->start, b->cap += BUFSIZ, 1, &b->end);       
        }                                                                          
        *b->end++ = c;                                                             
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
void *                                                                             
xrealloc(void *buf, size_t num, size_t siz, void *endvp)                           
{                                                                                  
        char **endp = endvp;                                                       
        char *b = buf;                                                             
        ptrdiff_t offset = b && endp && *endp ? *endp - b : 0;                     
        b = realloc(b, num * siz);                                                 
        if( b == NULL ){                                                           
                perror("realloc");                                                 
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                
        }                                                                          
        if( endp != NULL ){                                                        
                *endp = b + offset;                                                
        }                                                                          
        return b;                                                                  
}                                                                                  
                                                                                   
FILE *                                                                             
xfopen(const char *path, const char *mode)                                         
{                                                                                  
        FILE *fp = fopen(path, mode);                                              
        if( fp == NULL ){                                                          
                perror(path);                                                      
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);                                                
        }                                                                          
        return fp;                                                                 
}
```